# Python 3 code works as intended but i dont understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code:**

```
inv = {'arrow': 12, 'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'dagger': 1}

def show_inv():
    print('inventory:')
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inv.items():
        print(str(v)+ ' ' + (k))
        item_total = item_total + v
    print('total number of items: ' + str(item_total))

show_inv()
```

**Result(As Expected):**

> inventory:
>
> 12 arrow
>
> 42 gold coin
>
> 1 rope
>
> 6 torch
>
> 1 dagger
>
> total number of items: 62

but how does

```
item_total = item_total + v
```

give me the correct total of values?

Edit: why does print(str(v)) alone always give me the value to the 'dagger' key?

Comment: It's just adding the dictionary's values together to give you the total.

Comment: each iteration, it's adding the number of that current item to the running total number of items `item_total + v`, then storing that updated value back into `item_total = ...`

Comment: If you're confused about the fact that `item_total` is being assigned to `item_total + v` - the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated first before assignment occurs, so everything works as you intend.

Comment: You could simply use the `sum` function and omit the `item_total` altogether, like: `sum(v for k, v in inv.items())`.

Comment: no but see why does  print(str(v)) alone always give me the value to the 'dagger' key?

Comment: it doesn't *always give the value to the 'dagger' key*, it always gives the value of the key which is the current iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The important lines here are:

```
for k, v in inv.items():
  # do stuff
```

When you use a `for`-loop on a dictionary's `items` iterator, it will loop over both `key`s and `value`s of that dictionary. As you have a dictionary from names to values, the `values` (`v`) will be the value of each item. Adding all of them gives you the correct total value.

The line

```
item_total = item_total + v
```

runs once for every item in the inventory, because it is within a `for`-loop that runs over the inventory.

Reading about [Iterators in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) might help you understand why this works.